# Rails app Sidekiq high memory usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-management, sidekiq

I have a Rails 4 app deployed on Digital Ocean using Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.  The app seems to run fine but the system runs at 95% memory all the time.  I even upgraded the droplet to double the RAM and it's still at 95%.

Here is my top output:

```
top - 11:03:54 up  8:37,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.03, 0.05
Tasks: 118 total,   1 running, 117 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.2 us,  0.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   2049956 total,  1980616 used,    69340 free,     8708 buffers
KiB Swap:  1048572 total,  1036928 used,    11644 free.    47864 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                               
 7510 ubuntu    20   0  780436 274428   2540 S   0.0 13.4   0:27.66 ruby                                                                                                                                                                  
 1313 root      20   0 1921472 250948   2700 S   0.0 12.2   1:42.70 bundle                                                                                                                                                                
 1315 root      20   0 1876992 246204   2664 S   0.0 12.0   1:44.10 bundle                                                                                                                                                                
 1359 root      20   0 1928636 236168   2692 S   0.0 11.5   1:42.58 bundle                                                                                                                                                                
 6408 ubuntu    20   0  781764 175368   2244 S   0.3  8.6   1:10.81 ruby                                                                                                                                                                  
 8681 ubuntu    20   0  984140 156708   1884 S   0.3  7.6   1:37.95 ruby                                                                                                                                                                  
 8810 ubuntu    20   0  646824 117356   2548 S   0.0  5.7   0:11.07 ruby                                                                                                                                                                  
 8821 ubuntu    20   0  646920 112728   2532 S   0.0  5.5   0:11.48 ruby                                                                                                                                                                  
 8797 ubuntu    20   0  646728  82372   2960 S   0.0  4.0   0:14.33 ruby                                                                                                                                                                  
 1932 ubuntu    20   0  332292  56948   1552 S   0.0  2.8   0:04.88 ruby
```

I know there are tons of blog posts etc. on Rail app memory optimization.  The 3 bundle processes are what confuses me.  My app (actually 2 apps - one production and one staging) uses Redis / Sidekiq which are the bundle processes.  So my question(s) are:

1) Is this 'normal'?

2) If not is there a way to start troubleshooting this?

**UPDATE**

Here is the top output:

```
ubuntu@rails-01:~$ ps aux --sort=-%mem
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      1291  8.8  9.4 846856 194624 ?       Sl   18:04   0:23 sidekiq 4.2.10 production [0 of 3 busy]                                                                                  
root      1411  8.9  9.4 846824 194532 ?       Sl   18:04   0:24 sidekiq 4.2.10 production [0 of 3 busy]                                                                                  
root      1272  9.1  9.4 712752 193516 ?       Sl   18:04   0:24 sidekiq 4.2.10 staging [0 of 1 busy]                                                                                  
ubuntu    2254  0.6  9.3 645792 192648 ?       Sl   18:05   0:01 Passenger RubyApp: /home/ubuntu/production/current/public (production)
ubuntu    1986  0.6  9.3 645048 192064 ?       Sl   18:05   0:01 Passenger RubyApp: /home/ubuntu/staging/current/public (staging)
ubuntu    1762  9.8  9.2 375520 190264 ?       Sl   18:04   0:24 Passenger AppPreloader: /home/ubuntu/production/current   
ubuntu    1678  9.5  9.2 374872 189588 ?       Sl   18:04   0:25 Passenger AppPreloader: /home/ubuntu/staging/current      
ubuntu    2082  0.2  9.1 645144 187524 ?       Sl   18:05   0:00 Passenger RubyApp: /home/ubuntu/staging/current/public (staging)
ubuntu    1839  2.9  3.9 197300 79976 ?        Sl   18:04   0:06 Passenger AppPreloader: /home/ubuntu/landing/current      
ubuntu    1962  0.1  3.8 332292 78720 ?        Sl   18:05   0:00 Passenger RubyApp: /home/ubuntu/landing/current/public (production)
ubuntu    1969  0.0  3.7 332388 76044 ?        Sl   18:05   0:00 Passenger RubyApp: /home/ubuntu/landing/current/public (production)
```

I forgot I have 2 production workers on the server and 1 staging.  I had concurrency at 5 and 2 but I then lowered that to 3 and 1.  All Sidekiq is doing is some low level upload image processing and bulk record creations, updated and deletes that I don't want the user to sit around waiting for a page load on.

I am now seeing it level off at 80%.  Better but still seems high.  I think the next will be lots of code optimization etc.  I am sure I have lots of things I can find here.

Comment: Can you post the output of `ps au --sort=-%mem`? That will show the complete command and will confirm what those `bundle` processes are actually calling. Also, can you post the `top` output of your previous droplet? It will help to compare both outputs.

Comment: I am guessing you meant `ps aux --sort=-%mem`

Answer (score 1):

There's tons of reasons why your Ruby process might be eating too much memory.  Any gem or app code can allocate any amount of memory so in general, it is impossible for SO to tell you why.  Here's one possible reason:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27002#issuecomment-260086170

Comment: Thanks Mike - I know I have lots of clean / refactoring etc. to do which I am sure will help.

Answer (score 1):

Keep an eye on how many Sidekiq processes do you have running, what is the configured concurrency, the polling and also the number of queues you use. A high number of any of those can cause high memory usage. You can tweak those values in your `sidekiq.yml` and test-drive how they affect to your environment.

For more info: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options

Comment: This is the best answer - my code will effect that but the concurrency was the biggest one by far.  Thanks

Comment: Hmmmm... WTH. It dropped right off to 80% but now slowly creeped right back to 95%